# SVG Icons in React don't show

Tags: html, css, reactjs, svg

I have a problem with uploading SVG icons in React. I added svg-inline-loader to webpack, but it doesn't show an icon. It just show unfound pic. I'd like to add SVG icons as img src, background-image and shortcut icon.

EDIT:

This is my webpack.config

```
module.exports = {
entry: ["whatwg-fetch", "./js/app.jsx"],
output: {
    filename: "./js/out.js"
},
devServer: {
    inline: true,
    contentBase: './',
    port: 3001
},
watch: true,

module: {
    loaders: [{
        test: /\.jsx$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
            presets: ['es2015','stage-2', 'react']
        }
    }, {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loader: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
        },
        {
            test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: [
                {
                    loader: 'file-loader',
                    options: {
                        name: '[path][name].[ext]'
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            test: /\.svg$/,
            loader: 'svg-inline-loader'
        }
    ]
}
};
```

Comment: You can always just change the svg file into a jsx file. Do you need to be shown how?

Comment: Well, I have never used svg files before at all, so I don't know how :/

Answer (score 0):

`jsx` transpiles your code into vanilla javascript and supports `svg`s. So in the same way you can make `<div>`s, you can make `<svg>`s.

Open up the svg file in your text editor and change the file type to `jsx`. Just adjust the code to jsx after that. The following is 100% valid jsx that looks identical to what you originally have in a native svg. There are lots of elements in a native svg that you can remove, but as you can see, the concepts are the same.

```
import * as React from 'react';
//I have this file named as lightning.jsx
const SVG= (
<svg
    className="control-lightning"
    viewBox="0 0 483.73 483.73"
>
    <g>
        <polygon 
            points="119.637,282.441 192.449,282.441 165.869,
            483.73 364.094,189.622 296.631,189.622 325.678,0"
        />
    </g>
</svg>
);

export default SVG;
```

Try importing this into your project and rendering it. It will be an unstyled lightning bolt.

Comment: Oh, that really helped me. You're awesome :)

Comment: No problem! The nice thing about writing it this way is that you can also use CSS classes to style it. CSS supports svg styles such as `stroke`, `fill`, `transition`, etc. Feel free to upvote and mark as correct if you like this answer ;)